# Vue Js paragraph display -> ok but checkbox doesn't works

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, qcheckbox

I need call 3 times the same POST API call on mounted and get the response.

The response of api is stored on vuex.

If i do paragraph that works:

{{answer1}} // displayed 2

{{answer2}} // displayed 1

{{answer3}} // displayed 0

but my checkbox doesn't works on first launch but if i save my document and it re-render thats's works....:

```
<el-checkbox v-model="...." :disabled="answer1 > 0 ?'false':'true'" ></el-checkbox>
```

my mounted call api :

```
async mounted(){

 await this.actionSetanswer1({
            props1: '..',
            props2: '..',
        }).then(() => {
            this.actionSetanswer2({
                props1: '...',
                props2: '...',
            }).then(() => {
                this.actionSetanswer3({
                    props1: '...',
                    props2: '...',
                })
            })
        })
}
```

Thanks you very much in advance
NB : this.$forceUpdate() doesn't work too...

Answer (score 1):

you can add a loading state:

```js
// script
data() {
  return {
    isLoading: true
  }
},
mounted() {
  // ...
  .then(() => {
    this.actionSetanswer3({
       props1: '...',
       props2: '...',
    }).then(() => {
       this.isLoading = false
    })
}
```

```html
// template
<el-checkbox v-if="!isLoading" v-model="...." :disabled="answer1 > 0 ?'false':'true'" />
```